# transforming coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot a series of rectangles and lines based on a tab delimited text file in matplotlib. The coordinates are quite large in the data and shown be drawn to scale -- except scaled down by some factor X -- in matplotlib.

What's the easiest way to do this in matplotlib? I know that there are transformations, but I am not sure how to define my own transformation (i.e. where the origin is and what the scale factor is) in matplotlib and have it easily convert between "data space" and "plot space".  Can someone please show a quick example or point me to the right place?

Comment: This is the best tutorial on transforms.  http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutorial.html.  I'm having trouble understanding your request as "data space" and "plot space" seem synonyms to me.  Maybe you mean "figure coordinates" which would be in pixels?  An example of the data and the desired outcome would be helpful.  Your particular transform seems simple enough not to bother with the built-in tranform objects.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with matplotlib.  I want my scales to be fractal space coordinates, but that data itself is in image coordinates.  I want a simple way to convert the transform, but my image coordinates are not fixed.  They can vary.  I also want the fractal coordinates zoom and pan to cause an event to recalculate a new data set and apply it to the current fractal coordinates shown on the screen.  So the transform must be aware of the data set resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply use matplotlib's plot function, the plot will fit into one online window, so you don't really need to 'rescale' explicitly. Linearly rescaling is pretty easy, if you include some code sample to show your formatting of the data, somebody can help you in translating the origin and scaling the coordinates.